# передать контекст из views в template

Tags: python, django

В папке templates лежит шаблон

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

с таким кодом

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как передать в шаблон контекст с именем view
отсюда

```
def template_two(request):
# name = "template_two"
return render(request, 'myView.html')
```

Пока что рисуется страница без переменной `name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def template_two(request):
    return render(request, 'myView.html', {'name': 'Romik'})
```

Comment: благодарочка!!!